# How to automatically restart a failed startup application

Tags: unity, startup

I'm running [rescuetime](https://www.rescuetime.com/) on Ubuntu 16.04 as a startup application.

```
$ cat .config/autostart/rescuetime.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/rescuetime
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_GB]=RescueTime
Name=RescueTime
Comment[en_GB]=
Comment=
```

Unfortunately rescuetime often fails. How do I restart a startup application? Can I make it restart automatically?

Comment: I think you can use Upstart user jobs: http://askubuntu.com/a/518440/158442 (Even though systemd is init, upstart handles user sessions, iirc), and it can restart tasks if `respawn` is specified in the job configuration

Comment: I can't even get rescuetime to work on ubuntu 16.04 at all. The applet doesnt appear and no time is logged in the app. Any advice with this?

Comment: @ubuntu_uk_user Are you sure you installed the correct package? Probably 64bit is what you need.

Comment: @NieldeWet I have installed the right package. Just running rescuetime seems to do nothing. Everytime I open the rescuetime deb it asks me to install the package again (even though I already went through the installation process)